# How to make sure I don't run into undefined values when loading and working with a JSON from the internet?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have ran into this multiple times when trying to work with async funtions that load data.
I can use them to iterate trought them but I cannot console.log them nor do .foreach on them, becasue of some load order.

I worked around it multiple times by just passing the value around afew times until the data "solidified".

The tutorial implementaitons always only seem to work for when you get the data and instantly put them into the right objects that have the exact format of the JSON.
But I'm in my case I only want to store parts of the JSON and I also want to convert some parts of it to different values after the JSON have loaded.

How could I make sure that the data I'm working on is already loaded when I try to work with it?

Here is my current code:

Service

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }


  public async getJSON(url: string): Promise<Observable<any>> {

    // Call the http GET
    return this.http.get<Response>(url).pipe(map(this.extractData)
    );
  }

  public async getTags(postData: any) {
    let tags = [];
    await postData['tags']['species'].array.forEach(tag => { //This throws the error
      tags.push(this.tags[tag]);
    });
    return tags;
  }
```

Component:

```
posts: Post[] = [];
  constructor(private feedService: FeedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchPosts();

  }

  async fetchPosts() {
    var counter: number = 0;
    (await this.feedService.getJSON(this.url)).subscribe(
      async data => {
        console.log(data)
        try {
          while (data['posts'][counter]['file']['url']) {

            //var newPost: Post = { id: data['posts'][counter]['id'], flavor: "", source: }
            console.log(this.feedService.getTags(data['posts'][counter])); //Dummy code

            counter++;
          }
        } catch {
        }
      }
    )

  }
```

The current error which is caused by the data not being actually there:
[image]

I wish everyone a nice day/night!

Comment: Code you posted is very strange. You use subscribe with promises? You use await with array.forEach? Your async fetchPosts return nothing? etc... How many errors you have there 69?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov The async and await I added incase they make the code work. They are usually not there. The fetchPosts would fill an array with posts but it cannot work jet. I don't know much about the promise part. That is how it was in a nother stack overflow thread I think.
I jsut want to get json and work with it without running into undefined values.